# OS X, Cocoa: How to highlight burned-out areas of a photo?

Tags: image, macos, cocoa, bitmap, core-image

I've got an app that displays photos using `NSImage` – specifically, -`[NSImage drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:]`.  I want to highlight areas of the photo that are completely burned out (maximum values in all components, pure white) using a color like red, as some digital cameras and image processing apps do, to help the user see whether the image is overexposed, and how badly.

I've been scratching my head as to how to do this.  Options I've considered:

- I could probably write a Core Image filter to do it; none of the built-in filters look up to the task.  That seems like overkill, though; I've been reading through the docs, and it looks fairly complicated.  Big learning curve.
- I could scan through the bitmap data for the image and modify it as necessary.  This is easy enough to code for one bitmap format, but the multitude of bitmap formats make it a rather annoying exercise, and speed is important here, so writing general-purpose code that renders the image up to some maximal common format and works on that bitmap would be too big a speed penalty.
- As it happens, I am already scanning through images (handling all the different bitmap formats) at an earlier point in the code, to generate histogram data for the images.  I could pretty easily add code at that point that would remember the burned-out pixels for later use.  I'm not quite sure what the best way is to do that, though.  A 1-bit-per-pixel NSBitmapImageRep?  How would I draw it later, making the 1-pixels draw red and the 0-pixels draw transparent, for example?  I don't want to make a 32-bit `NSBitmapImageRep` with an alpha channel and everything just for this purpose, as memory is not infinite and images are large.  But there must be a way to draw a 1-bit mask in a given color, somehow.

Before forging ahead with one of these approaches, I thought I'd see whether anybody here has a better idea.  Or maybe has implemented the CI filter in question already?  Apart from the learning curve, that seems like the best approach I've thought of so far – no memory overhead, and probably faster than other options, too.

Thanks...

Ben Haller
Stick Software

---

OK, I implemented my own Core Image filter to do this.  Wasn't as hard as I expected, although the documentation is not great for this stuff.  The doc examples all assume you're using ARC, so if you're not, following those examples will give you various retain/release bugs.  There was also a little weirdness with the CIFilterConstructor stuff, which did not quite go as documented.  But overall pretty easy.  CI is cool.  My code is below, for anybody who might find it useful:

```
Header:

    #import 

    @interface SSTintHighlightsFilter : CIFilter
    {
        CIImage *inputImage;
        CIColor *highlightColor;
    }
    @end

Implementation file:

    #import "SSTintHighlightsFilter.h"

    static CIKernel *tintHighlightsFilter = nil;

    @implementation SSTintHighlightsFilter

    + (void)initialize
    {
        [CIFilter registerFilterName:@"SSTintHighlightsFilter" constructor:(id )self
                     classAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Tint Highlights", kCIAttributeFilterDisplayName, [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kCICategoryColorAdjustment, kCICategoryStillImage, nil], kCIAttributeFilterCategories, nil]];
    }

    + (CIFilter *)filterWithName:(NSString *)name
    {
        CIFilter *filter = [[self alloc] init];

        return [filter autorelease];
    }

    - (id)init
    {
        if (!tintHighlightsFilter)
        {
            NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
            NSString *code = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"tintHighlightsAndShadows" ofType:@"cikernel"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];
            NSArray *kernels = [CIKernel kernelsWithString:code];

            tintHighlightsFilter = [[kernels objectAtIndex:0] retain];
        }

        return [super init];
    }

    - (NSDictionary *)customAttributes
    {
        NSDictionary *attrs = @{
              @"highlightColor" : @{ kCIAttributeClass : [CIColor class], kCIAttributeType : kCIAttributeTypeOpaqueColor }
        };

        return attrs;
    }

    - (CIImage *)outputImage
    {
        CISampler *src = [CISampler samplerWithImage:inputImage];

        return [self apply:tintHighlightsFilter
                 arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:src, highlightColor, nil]
                   options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[src definition], kCIApplyOptionDefinition, nil]];
    }

    @end

tintHighlights.cikernel:

    kernel vec4 tintHighlights(sampler inputImage, __color highlightColor)
    {
        vec4 originalColor, tintedColor;
        float sum;

        // fetch the source pixel
        originalColor = sample(inputImage, samplerCoord(inputImage));

        // calculate the color component sum as a way of testing whether we are black or white
        sum = originalColor.r + originalColor.g + originalColor.b;

        // replace pixels that are white with the highlight color
        tintedColor = (sum > 2.99999999999999999999999) ? highlightColor : originalColor;

        // preserve alpha
        tintedColor.a = originalColor.a;

        return tintedColor;
    }

using the filter:

    + (NSImage *)showHighlightsInImage:(NSImage *)img dstRect:(NSRect)dstRect
    {
        NSGraphicsContext *currentContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
        NSRect dstRectForCGImage = dstRect;     // because the method below wants a pointer, and I don't trust it not to modify my rect...
        CGImageRef cgImage = [img CGImageForProposedRect:&dstRectForCGImage context:currentContext hints:nil];
        CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];

        [SSTintHighlightsFilter class];     // get my filter initialized

        CIFilter *highlightFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"SSTintHighlightsFilter"];

        [highlightFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
        [highlightFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"highlightColor"];
        [inputImage release];

        CIImage *outputImage = [highlightFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

        NSImage *resultImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[img size]];
        [resultImage addRepresentation:[NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage:outputImage]];

        return [resultImage autorelease];
    }
```

I'm not sure that I'm handling the alpha entirely robustly, with premultiplication issues and so forth, but apart from that possible glitch it is working great.

Comment: You may be able to get the results you're after using the `CISpotColor` filter.

Comment: Aha!  I don't know how I missed that, thanks!  Now I have:
<pre>
CIFilter *hf = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISpotColor"];
[hf setDefaults];
[hf setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[hf setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor1"];
[hf setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor1"];
[hf setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.001] forKey: @"inputCloseness1"];
[hf setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey: @"inputContrast1"];
  
</pre>This highlights in red, but it also munges the image.

Comment: @duskwuff It appears that the second and third replacement colors are also used, and that munges the images.  I can't figure out how to deactivate that.  Removing the -setDefaults call gives errors that parameters haven't been set; adding sets of 0 for the closeness of color 2 and 3 doesn't work.  How can I use CISpotColor to replace just a single color??  I can't find any documentation on it at all, beyond the list of parameters given in the Core Image Filter Reference.  (And sorry, I'm new here and can't figure out how to format the code in my previous comment to look nice...)

Comment: Even if you set all three source colors to white? That's disappointing… never mind, then.

Comment: @duskwuff Yeah, if I set all three input colors and associated parameters in the same way that I set the first, then the burned-out area turns red as desired, but the whole rest of the image turns white.  I suspect I just don't know how to use this filter properly – I have no idea what the "contrast" parameters do – but there seems to be no documentation on it at all, which is frustrating.  Anyway, as a proof of concept it certainly indicates that Core Image can do what I want and can do it fast.  I may try to write my own filter.  Yikes.

Comment: Added a solution above.  Core Image is very cool.  @duskwuff thanks for pushing me in that direction.